# Class instance variable initialize in extended module

Tags: ruby

I know there is should be a way to initialize class instance variable that added by a module via extend
example:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :count

    def self.count
      @count = 0
    end

    count
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def register
      # self.class.count = 0 if self.class.count.nil?
      self.class.count += 1
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include MyModule

  private

  def initialize
    register
  end

end
```

In ClassMethods should be a way to initialize count, but i always catch error "undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass"
When i perform

```
f = Foo.new
```

No problem in module InstanceMethods if i uncomment line

```
# self.class.count = 0 if self.class.count.nil?
```

Work correctly!

Comment: `attr_accessor :count` defines attributes acces for instance variables.

Comment: If you're using a recent ruby, `include` is no longer a private method.  Which means, no need to `send` it. Just `base.include InstanceMethods`

Comment: `initialize` is by default private, so you can omit the explicit `private` in `Foo`.

Comment: @Stefan: I'll be damned, it IS private. It hasn't occurred to me until now :)

Comment: Sergio thanks for the tip about base.include :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could move the variable initialization into the `included` callback:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.include InstanceMethods
    base.count = 0
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :count
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def register
      self.class.count += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a possibility, yes.

Answer (score 3):

One bit too many `self` in your code. You already `extend` your `ClassMethods` module. `extend` uses instance methods, not class methods. So your module should look like this (rest of the code unchanged).

```
module ClassMethods

  def count
    @count ||= 0
  end

  attr_writer :count
end
```

Then it works

```
Foo.count # => 0
Foo.new
Foo.count # => 1
```

Comment: I got this:
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @D.K.S Must be you didn't copy my code exactly. Or you changed something else in the other code.